# plotly.figure_factory.create_scatterplot stopped working?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, scatter-plot

I was using plotly to try some things and then found that create_scatterplot is the only package that doesn't work.
I mean, it clearly is in the module, as it appears when you call the help command:

```
NAME
plotly.figure_factory

FILE
     /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/__init__.py

 PACKAGE CONTENTS
    _2d_density
    _annotated_heatmap
    _bullet
    _candlestick
    _county_choropleth
    _dendrogram
    _distplot
    _facet_grid
    _gantt
    _ohlc
    _quiver
    _scatterplot
    _streamline
    _table
 :
```

[And in the plotly.py/plotly/figure_factory github folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgS9w.png)

Is it down or something? I am quite new to programming, but I thought this kind of thing stayed local. Maybe I am losing something, can i fix this?

If you want to check some code:

```
from plotly import figure_factory as ff
help(ff)
from plotly.figure_factory import create_2d_density
from plotly.figure_factory import create_annotated_heatmap
from plotly.figure_factory import create_bullet
from plotly.figure_factory import create_candlestick
from plotly.figure_factory import create_county_choropleth
from plotly.figure_factory import create_dendrogram
from plotly.figure_factory import create_facet_grid
from plotly.figure_factory import create_gantt
from plotly.figure_factory import create_ohlc
from plotly.figure_factory import create_quiver
from plotly.figure_factory import create_scatterplot
from plotly.figure_factory import create_streamline
from plotly.figure_factory import create_table
```

And you can see it only returns errors with scatterplot and county_choropleth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in github plotly.figure_factory at [_county_choropleth](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/figure_factory/_county_choropleth.py) you need just call this in another way:

```
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth
```

and call after:

```
fig = create_choropleth(bla-bla)
py.plot(fig, filename='basic-choropleth')
```

In situation with [scatterplot](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/figure_factory/_scatterplot.py) you will need rename `create_scatterplot` to just `scatterplot`:

```
from plotly.figure_factory._scatterplot import scatterplot
```

and:

```
fig = scatterplot(bla-bla)
py.plot(fig, filename='basic-scatter')
```

Also I found that when you called `create_choropleth` you need to install few packages [link](https://github.com/plotly/documentation/issues/959) to avoid troubles:

```
pip install shapely
pip install geopandas
pip install pyshp
```

And don`t forget to update your plotly version:

```
pip install --upgrade plotly
```

Hope this information could help you

Comment: @cosme-fulanito, if this help you?