# Using Geopandas and the county-choropleth module

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, gdal, geopandas, choropleth

[image]I am unable to get figure_factory to recognize the county_choroplet module which contains create_choropleth (on line 512 I believe).

I am just using a basic example from the plotly website
https://plot.ly/python/county-choropleth/

Edit: Ive tried to implement suggestions from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138413/plotly-figure-factory-create-scatterplot-stopped-working/52148045#52148045) by importing as:

```
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth
```

and then:
`fig = create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
py.ploy(fig, filename='basic-choropleth')
py.iplot(fig, filename='choropleth of some cali counties - full usa scope')`

But i receive the following error (in picture):

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona__init__.py", line 162, in open
    raise IOError("no such file or directory: %r" % path)

OSError: no such file or directory: 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\package_data\gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.shp'

[image: my code]

[image: install libraries]

Comment: Try using answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138413/plotly-figure-factory-create-scatterplot-stopped-working/52148045#52148045). It is look similar to your problem

Comment: So i tried to implement the changes suggested here by importing as 
                 
`from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth` and then ran the following:
                               `fig = create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
py.ploy(fig, filename='basic-choropleth')
py.iplot(fig, filename='choropleth of some cali counties - full usa scope')`           however i then recieved an error code           OSError: no such file or directory: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\package_data\\gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.shp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is did was transfer the files in `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs\plotly-3.1.1-py36h28b3542_0\Lib\site-packages\plotly`

to:

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly
```

Then I ran the code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth

py.sign_in('chessybo', 'XXXXXXXXXXX')

fips = ['06021', '06023', '06027',
        '06029', '06033', '06059',
        '06047', '06049', '06051',
        '06055', '06061']
values = range(len(fips))

#fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
fig = create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
#py.plotly(fig, filename='basic-choropleth')
py.plot(fig, filename='choropleth of some cali counties - full usa scope')
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you will get after executing this code:

```
# import necessary libraries
import geopandas
import shapely
import shapefile
import plotly
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth

# Check your plotly version
print(plotly.__version__, geopandas.__version__,shapely.__version__,shapefile.__version__)
# Data
fips = ['06021','06023','06027',
        '06029','06033','06059',
        '06047','06049','06051',
        '06055','06061']
values = range(len(fips))
# Create fig
fig = create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
# Plot in offline mode and save plot in your Python script folder
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='choropleth_usa.html')
```

Just in my case, script return the following:
[image: Choropleth_USA]

Comment: I receive the following:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 162, in open
    raise IOError("no such file or directory: %r" % path)

OSError: no such file or directory: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\package_data\\gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.shp'

Comment: @clay-chester, are you installed `shapely`,`geopandas`,`pyshp`?

Comment: I ran conda install geopandas. pyshp-1.2.12-py3.6.egg-info is in my site-packages library however it contains no modules, only .txt files. I've tried to conda install it but it just gives me this egg thing. I have a shapefiles folder in a package names "cartopy". (shapefile is what pyshp is suppose to be i think

Comment: @clay-chester, I am suggest you to run my code again for check if any from there packages installed uncorrectly (updated slightly). I thought here will be a problem with one or another packages. And if found one, uninstall and install from `pip`, not the `conda`

Comment: so from what ive read about installing geopandas, they keep saying not to install pip if youre a conda user. I thought that conda was my environment so "conda install" would put it in the correct place. if i install it with pip, then it wont be in my environment, correct? im worried about using pip since i believe it may mess up what i do have